# Embedding images in web page

Tags: performance, http, png

I have a web page that has to load a bunch of small PNG images. Number of iamges and which images need to be embedded is dynamic and depends on parameters. Each image is approx 20 kb.

Is there an option to embed images in html to reduce number of http requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that via : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

This works on all browsers except IE. To support IE, you would need to use a JavaScript URI that returns a base 64 PNG Data.

Answer (score 0):

If your images are icons or the like, you can try the "sprite" method to reduce the number of HTTP request. Put all images in a single image, and use CSS to display only the needed part of the main image